# Webapp logging settings are being ignored

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, opensuse, gentoo

I'm not able to get output with priority lower than INFO from a webapp. Everything other is being logged correctly.

Log shows the following, yet actual settings put in to the file are seem to be ignored:

> INFO: Initializing log4j from
>   [/var/lib/tomcat-7-main/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/log4j.properties]

Content of the file is following:

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.conversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.logger.my.webapp=TRACE

log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=TRACE
```

This configuration works correctly with another machine running openSUSE (while the issue is related to machine running Gentoo). Both of them running Tomcat 7 under Oracle JDK 1.7. Any ideas?

Comment: If you add `-Dlog4j.debug` to the command line used to start Tomcat then log4j will print a bunch of diagnostic information to the console (typically redirected to `logs/catalina.out`. This might help you isolate the problem.

Comment: Adding this to JAVA_OPTS enables some additional output to logs, but there's nothing useful there.

Comment: `another machine`? Is it the same application?

Comment: Yes. The same version of the same app. Another workstation.

Comment: Same version of log4j.jar? TRACE is a relatively recent addition. If your app or tomcat contains an older version then you may have this problem